# IPSEC between two offices with SAME local networks. How should I do nat?

Tags: nat, ipsec

[image]
I have two spokes with same local networks and want to do IPSEC between them.
When I try to ping 172.17.214.111 from 192.168.5.0 (from right side to left side) I see packet on Cisco router and I see reply from 172.17.214.111 on that cisco router too. And that packet routed properly to IPSEC tunnel. But ping doesn't work. (timeout) What I do wrong?

Comment: This article I wrote might be helpful or you:  [How to do NAT for a VPN with overlapping IP Networks](https://www.practicalnetworking.net/stand-alone/vpn-overlapping-networks/).

Answer (score 3):

You can't have two separate networks with the same subnet. The best solution is to readdress one of them.

Other possible solutions, such as using NAT or some type of layer 2 tunneling, are more complicated and subject to errors than readdressing.

Answer (score 1):

As per you diagram and explanation I can see that both end users networks are using same network subnet 192.168 5.0/24, in the case source and destination ip will be belong to same subnet ips will get conflict in this case to overcome this issue . Please use different ip pool subnet for Source natting purpose from traffic iniation side .

`Assuming right side is initiating traffic  do source natting for source subnet 192.168.5.0/24 with newly allocate pool`

Example allocate source nat pool 172.16.56.0/24 select the pool according which is not used in left-side network or peer network

`Ip nat inside source static 192.168.5.0 172.16.56.0`

`If you want to ping local ips on peers side ensure that ICMP is allowed on firewall security policy on both end`